# $match operator for sub document field in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying new pipeline query of MongoDB so i try to execute below query.

```
{
aggregate: 'Posts',
pipeline: [
    { $unwind: '$Comments'},
    { $match: {'$Comments.Owner': 'Harry' }},
    {$group: {
        '_id': '$Comments._id'
        }
     }
   ]
}
```

And nothing match to query so empty result returns. I guess problem can be on $match command . I am using dotted notation match comment Owner but not sure it is exactly true or not. Why this query does not return Ownders who is 'Harry' . I am sure it is exist in db.

Comment: Has any idea or guess ? I am able to use $match command on "Title" property of Post so i am sure "$Comments.Owner" syntax has a problem.

Comment: Can you post some sample documents in your collection to get a better idea of how the query should work? Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You don't use the `$` prefix for the `$match` field names.

Try this:

```js
{
  aggregate: 'Posts',
  pipeline: [
    { $unwind: '$Comments'},
    { $match: {'Comments.Owner': 'Harry' }},
    { $group: {
      '_id': '$Comments._id'
    }}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I encounter the same problem with aggregation framework with MongoDB 2.2.

`$match` didn't work for me for subdocument (but I am just learning MongoDB, so I could do something wrong).

I added extra projection to remove subdocument (`Comments` in this case):

```
{
aggregate: 'Posts',
pipeline: [
    { $unwind: '$Comments'},
    { $project: {
      comment_id: "$Comments._id",
      comment_owner: "$Comments.Owner"
    }},
    { $match: {'$comment_Owner': 'Harry' }},
    {$group: {
        '_id': '$comment_id'
        }
     }
   ]
}
```